# Cannot convert undefined in object

Tags: javascript

In my application appear an error, and i can't understand why. Bellow i check if  `x` is undefined, give `Object.keys(test[0])`:

```js
const test = [
{
  id: '',
  key: '',
  name: '',
  email: '',
},
 ];
  
const demo = x!== undefined ? Object.keys(x[0]).map(a => {
      return {
        title: a,
        info: a,
        key: a,
      };
    })
  : Object.keys(test[0]).map(l => {
      return {
        title: l,
        info: l,
        key: l,
      };
    });
```

The issue appear when `x` is undefined, because i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`, at this line: `const demo = x!== undefined ? Object.keys(x[0]).map(a => {`
I don't understand why i get this response, because, i have a condition above, and in the case when i have `x` undefined, i should get the second solution `Object.keys(test[0])...`. Who know how to solve this?

Comment: Just because `x` is defined doesn't mean `x[0]` is defined

Comment: How about `typeof x === 'object' && Array.isArray(x) && x.length > 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

```
const demo = (x && Array.isArray(x) && x.length>0)? Object.keys(x[0]).map(a => {
      return {
        title: a,
        info: a,
        key: a,
      };
    })
  : Object.keys(test[0]).map(l => {
      return {
        title: l,
        info: l,
        key: l,
      };
    });
```